# Generate a filename with a number inside parentheses

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems

I'm working with ASP.NET project where the user can upload files to the server. I want to save the file with its original name, but if the file with the same name already exists, how can I generate a filename with a number in the parenthesis like Windows does?

Files are uploaded to a particular folder and saved with its client-side name itself. So, if a file named *myimage.jpg* is uploaded and a file with the same name already exists in the server, I need to rename it to *myimage(1).jpg* or if 'myimage.jpg' to 'myimage(n).jpg' exists, I need to rename it to  *myimage(n+1).jpg*.

What will be the best way to search for and generate such file names? My first guess was to use [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) with a regex over `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`, but is that a good approach?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: Mine was a bit ugly, used linq to select files with (wildcard)pattern filename(*).ext and return the max(number) found inside the parenthesis of the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static object lockObject = new object();
void UploadFile(...)
{
    //-- other code
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        int i = 1;
        string saveFileAs = "MyFile.txt";
        while (File.Exists(saveFileAs))
        {
           string fileNameWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(saveFileAs);
           string ext = Path.GetExtension(saveFileAs)
           saveFileAs = String.Concat(fileNameWithoutExt, "(", i.ToString(), ")", ext);
           i++;
        }

        //-- Now you can save the file.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in asp.net - which means there are multiple threads running the same logic; checking existence and saving the file must to atomic.

Comment: great point, I have updated the answer. It also helped me find an area in my project that was susceptible to this.

Comment: If the code runs in a server farm, the lock has to be done through a global place like file system or database.

Comment: excellent, thanks for keeping me on my toes. Now the OP has choices on safety.

Comment: does not work if the file you are trying to save if MyFile(2).txt and there is already a file named MyFile(2).txt

Comment: @anaval Then the file would become MyFile(2)(1).txt ?

Answer (score 6):

If the files with the same original name don't have to be shown sorted by upload date/time, you could simply append *System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()* to the file name.

Comment: Never underestimate the usefulness of GUIDs :)

Comment: That makes for a very ugly filename.

Comment: @SLaks: Indeed. But WhoaCoolPic(1357).jpg is not very pretty either :-)

Comment: Thanks, I considered that option already, but filename gets really long and user might get confused with the filenames as this file upload module is part of a light weight file manager built into the website.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need LINQ or regex.

If the original filename exists, append `(1)` to the name.
If that exists, append `(2)` to the (original) name.
And so on...